# SQL is it possible to grant permission to the view and not the user to access other db?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hello and thank you for your time,

I am using sql 2008
I created a db that has nothing of relevance in. Here I want to add views that access other databases. I will then add a user to the db with no relevance and give access to the view.

My obvious problem is that when the user tries to run the view, errors occur where they do not have permission to view the information. (when I use the admin type user, i can access the view and see the results no problem)

Can I create permissions to the view to all SELECT on the two seperate db's so the user can see the results. Or does the user require the read permissions on all the tables queried.

Thank you again.

This is what I tried (and many others but it did not work)

```
USE no-relevance-server
GRANT REFERENCES ON OBJECT[important-server::dbo.table] TO [the view]
```

Comment: Is the table the view references in another database on the same server, or a different server? Also does "did not work" mean the syntax you're showing generated an error, or you granted the permissions successfully but they weren't able to run a query?

Comment: They are on the same server, I just created a separate db to make it more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue here is one of cross database ownership chains

You can make it work by following the instructions at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/810474

```
EXEC sp_configure 'Cross DB Ownership Chaining', '1'; RECONFIGURE 
EXEC sp_dboption 'YourDatabase', 'db chaining', 'true'
```

But be sure to read up about `Cross Database Ownership Chaining` and the associated risks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. I understand what you mean, however I tried it with another user account that does have the privileges to view the tables on the other db and it works. so the chaining already exists.

Comment: So you can just `GRANT SELECT ON yourview TO youruser`?

Comment: Correct, however I get the error: 
The server principal "test-IT" is not able to access the database "IMPORTANT SERVER" under the current security context.
And i am trying to find a way to not add the permission to the user but instead just the view

Comment: `test-IT` needs to be a user on the database `Important-server` - but it doesn't need any permissions.

Comment: The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'table-needed', database 'Important-server', schema 'dbo'.
After adding the user to the db

Comment: It may be that I need to do grants on the actual View. I just dont know how to do it(since I would be trying to give selects on other db's

Comment: I also have to be doing something else wrong, I put the "view" in the important server and added the grant permission to the user he still gets the same error of permission denied on select for the tables

Comment: So, for the moment the only thing I can see doing, is adding the user on one of the two db's with access to just the view, and then just give them read access to the tables required on the other db..